# How to parse a custom \author format using xparse?

Tags: xparse, comma-separated-list

I want to allow using the \author command like this:

```
\author{John Doe <john.doe@example.com>, Someone Else <someone@example.com>}
```

And later parse the value to something like this:

```
\textsf{\textbf{John Doe}, \href{john.doe@example.com}{Email: john.doe@example.com}\\}
\textsf{\textbf{Someone Else}, \href{someone@example.com>}{Email: someone@example.com>}\\}
```

I already tried to do something like that using the `xparse` package:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\printauthor}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthor}{m}{ >{\SplitList{<}} m }{%
  \textsf{\textbf{#1}, \href{#2}{Email: #2}\\}
}

\printauthors{\theauthor}
```

Minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xparse}

\title{mwe}
\author{John Doe <john.doe@example.com>, Someone Else <someone@example.com>}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\printauthor}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthor}{ >{\SplitList{<}} m }{%
  \textsf{\textbf{#1}, \href{#2}{Email: #2}\\}
}

\begin{document}
\thetitle

\printauthors{\theauthor}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't seem to work like that. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is `\theauthors` supposed to do? Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: This is using the titling package (https://ctan.org/pkg/titling) and the article documentclass.

Comment: Please add the minimal document that has your issue.

Comment: @Christian Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split at commas and then parse for the email; with regexes it's (almost) easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{}
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:NV \g_bauer_authors_seq \theauthor
  \seq_clear:N \l__bauer_authors_out_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_bauer_authors_seq
   {
    \bauer_authors_parseemail:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__bauer_authors_out_seq { \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn { NV }
\seq_new:N \g_bauer_authors_seq
\seq_new:N \l__bauer_authors_out_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bauer_authors_parseemail:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { ([^<]*) } % anything up to <
   { \c{bauer_authors_format_author:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} }
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \<(.*)\> } % anything between < >
   { ,\ \c{bauer_authors_format_email:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} }
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_right:NV \l__bauer_authors_out_seq \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bauer_authors_format_author:n
 {
  \textsf { \textbf {\tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bauer_authors_format_email:n
 {
  \href{mailto:#1}{Email:~\texttt{#1}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{mwe}

\author{
  John Doe <john.doe@example.com>,
  Someone Else <someone@example.com>,
  No Mail
}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\LARGE\thetitle\\}

\bigskip

\printauthors
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is that each segment is transformed into

```
\bauer_authors_format_author:n { <name> }, \bauer_authors_format_email:n { <email> }
```

and then `\printauthors` will separate all segments with `\\`.

A different approach, with key-value arguments, that can be extended to accept other attributes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\authorlist}{m}
 {% a sequence of key-value items
  \keys_set:nn { bauer/authors } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{}
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_bauer_authors_seq \__bauer_authors_print:n
 }

\seq_new:N \g_bauer_authors_seq
\tl_new:N \l__bauer_authors_temp_tl

\keys_define:nn { bauer/authors }
 {
  author .code:n = \__bauer_authors_setup:n { #1 },
  email  .code:n = \__bauer_authors_email:n { #1 },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bauer_authors_setup:n
 {
  \tl_gset:Nx \l__bauer_authors_temp_tl { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
  \seq_gput_right:NV \g_bauer_authors_seq \l__bauer_authors_temp_tl
  \prop_new:c { g_bauer_authors_ \l__bauer_authors_temp_tl _prop }
  \prop_gput:cnn
   { g_bauer_authors_ \l__bauer_authors_temp_tl _prop }
   { author }
   { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bauer_authors_email:n
 {
  \prop_gput:cnn
   { g_bauer_authors_ \l__bauer_authors_temp_tl _prop }
   { email }
   { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bauer_authors_print:n
 {
  \bauer_authors_format_author:n
   {
    \prop_item:cn { g_bauer_authors_#1_prop } { author }
   }
  \prop_if_in:cnT { g_bauer_authors_#1_prop } { email }
   {
    ,~ % separation
    \bauer_authors_format_email:n
     {
      \prop_item:cn { g_bauer_authors_#1_prop } { email }
     }
   }
  \\ % new line
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bauer_authors_format_author:n
 {
  \textsf { \textbf {\tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bauer_authors_format_email:n
 {
  \href{mailto:#1}{Email:~\texttt{#1}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{mwe}

\authorlist{
  author = John Doe,
  email  = john.doe@example.com,
  author = Someone Else,
  email  = someone@example.com,
  author = No Mail
}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\LARGE\thetitle\\}

\bigskip

\printauthors
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

For each author a property list is allocated; a sequence works for indexing the authors.